# What API action is done for importing a Portfolio?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-service-catalog

I want to import a Portfolio that's shared with me but I'm unable to find the associated API action for it. (As I want to do it programmatically)

I'm looking for a translation in both Terraform as well as CFN of the specific API action and I can't seem to find it. Anyone an idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Terraform does not have a resource for this yet.

CloudFormation allows you to accept a portfolio share through the following resource:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-servicecatalog-acceptedportfolioshare.html